# Play all files in specific directory

Tags: asterisk

I am writing the custom dial plan. 
I need somehow to play all files in specific directory one by one in loop.
Is there a way to get list of files in directory before playing or have I to hardcode in the dial plan all the files I want to play?

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use agi  or agi-like bash script

For example script can generate somethign like

```
SET VARIABLE "file1:file2:file3:file4"
```

After that you can parse using CUT function in dialplan.

But agi is much simpler.